# Splitting a row into several rows in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have data set as follows:

```
id vala    valb
1  24      75
2  56      87
```

In this data set, there are two value types: `vala` and `valb`. The number of types may change, it can be three, four, etc.

I need to convert this first data set to:

```
id val type
1  24  a 
1  75  b
2  56  a
2  87  b
```

and then typeset it. Or without conversion, typeset the first data set in the format of the second data set.

`type` column is to differentiate `id`s, however it is not very necessary. If possible, it should be generated from the last character of the column names.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{testdataExisting.dat}
id vala    valb
1  24      75
2  56      87
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdataGenerated.dat}
id val type
1  24  a 
1  75  b
2  56  a
2  87  b
\end{filecontents}

 \begin{document}
Table 1

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,vala,valb},]{testdataExisting.dat}

Table 2

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,val,type},
    columns/type/.style={string type,column type=r},
 ]{testdataGenerated.dat}
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a new table with the element values correctly collected from the original table as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{testdataExisting.dat}
id vala    valb
1  24      75
2  56      87
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{testdataExisting.dat}\origtable

\begin{document}
Table 1

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,vala,valb}]\origtable

Table 2

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\origtable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\rr{2*\pgfmathresult}
\pgfplotstablenew[%
  create on use/newid/.style={%
  create col/assign/.code={%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\orr{\pgfplotstablerow/2}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\orr}{id}\of\origtable
  \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfplotsretval}},%
  create on use/newval/.style={%
  create col/assign/.code={%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\orr{\pgfplotstablerow/2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\occ{\pgfplotstablerow-2*\orr}
  \edef\ocol{\ifnum\occ=0 vala\else valb\fi}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\orr}{\ocol}\of\origtable
  \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfplotsretval}},%
  create on use/type/.style={%
  create col/assign/.code={%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\orr{\pgfplotstablerow/2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\occ{\pgfplotstablerow-2*\orr}
  \edef\otyp{\ifnum\occ=0 a\else b\fi}
  \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\otyp}},%
  columns={newid,newval,type}]{\rr}\newtable

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/type/.style={string type,column type=r}]\newtable
\end{document}
```

For the new table, there is a `create on use` for each column.  `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` is used as a handy way to get an integer value out and assign it to a macro.