# Dynamically add row depending on the values using PgfplotsTable

Tags: pgfplotstable

Consider the rows in table `testdataExisting.dat`:

- If `type=0`, `vala` must be put in a row. `valb` should not be displayed.
- If `type=1`, `vala` must be put in a row and `valb` must be put in the subsequent row with the same id, possibly via using `multirow`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{testdataExisting.dat}
id vala valb type
1  24   75   0
2  56   87   1
3  11   46   0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdataGenerated.dat}
id val  type
1  24   0
2  56   1
2  87   1
3  11   0
\end{filecontents}
 \begin{document}
Table 1

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,vala,valb,type},]{testdataExisting.dat}

Table 2

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,val,type},
    columns/type/.style={string type,column type=r},
 ]{testdataGenerated.dat}
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Here is a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112399/18654) of another problem that is similar to this problem. I could not adapt that solution for this problem. I was not able to handle addition of a new row which is triggered depending on the values. I need a solution using PgfplotsTable.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
\readdef{testdataExisting.dat}{\data}
\readArrayij{\data}{raw}{\ncols}

\begin{tabbing}
\= \Arrayij{raw}{1}{1} ~~~~~~\= val  ~~~~~\= \Arrayij{raw}{1}{\ncols}\\
\newcounter{index}\setcounter{index}{1}%
\whiledo{\value{index} < \nrows}{
  \addtocounter{index}{1}%
  \>\Arrayij{raw}{\value{index}}{1} \> \Arrayij{raw}{\value{index}}{2}%
                                   \> \Arrayij{raw}{\value{index}}{\ncols}\\
  \if 1\csname rawX\roman{index}Xiv\endcsname%
    \>\Arrayij{raw}{\value{index}}{1} \> \Arrayij{raw}{\value{index}}{3}%
                                   \> \Arrayij{raw}{\value{index}}{\ncols}\\
  \fi%
}
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

where the file `testdataExisting` is

```
id vala valb type
1  24   75   0
2  56   87   1
3  11   46   0
```

The output is:

[image]